# Powershell technique or algorithm to compare complex text?

Tags: algorithm, powershell, string-comparison

I have XML files I need to compare to each other. These websites represent my XML files.

A. https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/vmware_vsphere_6.5_esxi/

B. https://stigviewer.com/stig/vmware_vsphere_6.7_esxi/

So I can simply compare the Title to each other and that gets half my results. If it is a match I copy the modified code in A over to B. This leaves the the problem items like these.

A1. https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/vmware_vsphere_6.5_esxi/2021-06-23/finding/V-207602

B1. https://stigviewer.com/stig/vmware_vsphere_6.7_esxi/2021-03-17/finding/V-239258

Title nor Description match enough for me to make a determination, however, Check and Fix text areas are pretty close.

I created a datatable and loop thru each Vuln in A (above) and store VulnNum, Check_text and others. I then loop thru each Vuln in B and look for title matches and delete the row from datatable if matched, I store index non matching item of B to new array named ProcessID.

I then loop the ProcessID to finish 2nd level comparison.

```
$s1 = @"
PASTE CHECK TEXT FROM A1 link
"@
$s2 = @"
PASTE CHECK TEXT FROM B1 link
"@
[array]$a1 = ($s1 -split '\W').Where{$_}
[array]$b1 = ($s2 -split '\W').Where{$_}
$WordCount = (Compare-Object $a $b).where{$_.InputObject}.count #Number of words that are different
$WordCount
3
(Compare-Object $a1 $b1)

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
Web         <=           
set         <=           
to          <=
```

This method removes all non word characters and splits into an array, then simply compares the arrays
If $WordCount = 0 then exact match and I delete the row from datatable and start loop again.

I looked into soundex and LevenshteinDistance but doesn't seem workable solution.

Is there a better way to compare A1 to B1?

Comment: Bonus. rework this to make it faster.

[array]$a1 = ($s1 -split '\W').Where{$_}

Comment: Do you mean for your xml links?

[2021-06-23/MAC-3_Sensitive](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/vmware_vsphere_6.5_esxi/2021-06-23/MAC-3_Sensitive/xml)

And [2021-03-17/MAC-3_Sensitive](https://stigviewer.com/stig/vmware_vsphere_6.7_esxi/2021-03-17/MAC-3_Sensitive/xml)

Comment: The link is not exactly what I am working with but will do. In XML, look up 6.5 stig V-207602 and compare the check-content section and compare to V-239258 in 6.7 stig

Comment: Faster: `$a1=([regex]'\w+').matches($s1).Value` Running each on the Check Text from the A1 link 500 times showed an average time roughly 4 times faster for this than what you have.

Answer (score 0):

For (large) strings that are completely different (starting from the first few characters), normalizing both strings prior comparing them, might be pretty ineffective and expensive.
Instead, you might consider to use the [`IgnoreSymbols` Compare Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareoptions):

```
$a = '
From the vSphere Web Client select the ESXi Host and go to Configure >> System >> Security Profile. Scroll down to "Lockdown Mode" and verify it is set to Enabled (Normal or Strict).'

$b = '
From the vSphere Web Client select
the ESXi Host and go to
Configure > System > Security Profile.
Scroll down to "Lockdown Mode" and
verify it is set to Enabled
(Normal or Strict).'

$c = '
From the vSphere Client select the ESXi Host and go to Configure >> System >> Security Profile. Scroll down to "Lockdown Mode" and verify it is set to Enabled (Normal or Strict).'

[String]::Compare($a, $b, $Null, ('IgnoreCase', 'IgnoreSymbols')) -eq 0
True

[String]::Compare($a, $c, $Null, ('IgnoreCase', 'IgnoreSymbols')) -eq 0
False
```